# Why ReportViewer can't appear?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, reportviewer

Has been entered but hasn't yet appeared on the form. How can I choose report when not appear?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: You need to spend some time in the Help Center in order to learn what constitutes an acceptable question here.  You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which ALWAYS includes EXACTLY what you have done that makes you think you should be getting the result you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately for you, this is likely an issue that I've had some exposure to recently. There is an issue with recent versions of the report viewer NuGet package where they don't install certain components and the control does not appear on the form.  This is true of versions 150.1358.0 and 150.1357.0 I believe, but version 150.900.148 should be OK.

You will need to delete the control from the form, which you can do by first selecting it in the Document Outline window.  You can then downgrade you relevant NuGet package, then add a control from the Toolbox again.

Comment: I've tried it, I already installed the 15.900.148, but a new problem appeared, the ReportViewer from the toolbox couldn't be entered into the form, an error appeared like the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dacwj.png

Comment: I think that happens when there are still remnants of the later version in the project.  Can't recall exactly what I did when researching this last time but I would suggest that you remove all traces of the old version, which includes uninstalling the NuGet package, then rebuild the project and then add the correct version of the NuGet package.

Comment: oh, it works, thank you so much for helping, sorry for my ignorance, because I'm new